# System.NullReferenceException based on List<int>

Tags: c#, winforms, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to loop through rows and get their Indexes (Primary Keys from SQL).  I'm getting a NRE on "this.SelectRowIndexes.Add(ResourceKey)"  I can't figure out why it would matter and how can I fix this?

CODE:

```
    private void GetIndexes()
    {
        List<int> SelectRowIndexes = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < gridViewRecords.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)gridViewRecords.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
            DataRow selectedRow = drv.Row;
            ResourceKey = Convert.ToInt32(selectedRow["ResourceAndInstallKey"]);
            this.SelectRowIndexes.Add(ResourceKey);

        }
    }
```

I also have it up in my class (this has been a ton of troubleshooting, so my code looks terrible)

```
    public List<int> SelectRowIndexes { get; set; }
```

I had this prior.  Several of the answers quoted this code.  I changed mine because the if-else was actually used for something else, which has now been deleted

```
if (this.SelectRowIndexes == null)
{
    this.SelectRowIndexes.Add(ResourceKey);
}
else
{
    this.SelectRowIndexes.Add(ResourceKey);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you actually want to do if `this.SelectRowIndexes` is null? Currently you're just unconditionally calling `Add` on it, because both branches of your `if` statement do the same thing.

Note that it definitely *wouldn't* be null if you'd assigned a new value to it - but instead in this line, you're declaring a new local variable called `SelectRowIndexes`:

```
List<int> SelectRowIndexes = new List<int>();
```

... which you're then completely ignoring. Perhaps you meant to set the value of the property/field instead?

```
SelectRowIndexes = new List<int>();
```

With that change, you should avoid the exception - but you'll still have the basically-broken code. You should almost certainly just get rid of the `if` check... it's not doing you any good right now.

However, I would suggest that you probably *should* be declaring a separate local variable for `resourceKey` - the fact that you're updating an instance variable in a loop is somewhat peculiar... as is the fact that you're not using your loop index at all... you're doing the same thing for each iteration of the loop, using the current row rather than row `i`. Is that deliberate?

Fundamentally, you might well want to start this code again... it looks like you might just want to use LINQ:

```
private void GetIndexes()
{
    SelectRowIndexes = gridViewRecords.Rows
        .Cast<DataRowView>()
        .Select(drv => (int) drv.Row["ResourceAndInstallKey"])
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: the if statement was something I was trying on a different piece, which is gone now.  I'll update the code now

Comment: I put List<> instead of this.  Thank you.  I should have known that.

Comment: @KevinFischer: Well you don't need `this` at all unless you've got a local variable with the same name in scope...

Comment: Good point.  My Senior Dev likes it with a "this".  Their protocols.  Thank you again

Comment: @KevinFischer: It's a bad idea to edit the code in the question *after* a load of answers have been posted. You've now invalidated the points of various answers. I'll edit mine, but it would have been better if you'd left it as it was...

Comment: I added the old code to try to keep the previous answers associated with the post.

Answer (score 2):

If SelectRowIndexes is null then you can't add anything to the list. You first need to initialize an empty list with

```
this.SelectRowIndexes = new List<int>();
```

Comment: Now with the updated code its the line:
List<int> SelectRowIndexes = new List<int>();
remove the List<int> in front of it to initialize the property of the class instead of a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

You instantiate a local variable

```
List<int> SelectRowIndexes = new List<int>();
```

and then you are adding to your class property/field this.SelectedRowIndexes which you are most likely not assigning anywhere and it is null and you get NRE.

```
this.SelectRowIndexes.Add(ResourceKey);
```

Change this so

```
private void GetIndexes()
{
    this.SelectRowIndexes = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < gridViewRecords.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)gridViewRecords.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
        DataRow selectedRow = drv.Row;
        ResourceKey = Convert.ToInt32(selectedRow["ResourceAndInstallKey"]);
        this.SelectRowIndexes.Add(ResourceKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: Initially I didn't have the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword allows you to access a member named `SelectRowIndexes` within the scope of the class. That member is probably not initialized. Remove the `List<int>` type declaration and it will be perfect.

```
private List<int> SelectRowIndexes;
private void GetIndexes()
{
    SelectRowIndexes = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < gridViewRecords.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)gridViewRecords.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
        DataRow selectedRow = drv.Row;
        ResourceKey = Convert.ToInt32(selectedRow["ResourceAndInstallKey"]);
        if (this.SelectRowIndexes == null)
        {
            this.SelectRowIndexes.Add(ResourceKey);
        }
        else
        {
            this.SelectRowIndexes.Add(ResourceKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is the same for both paths of the if()

Comment: @cdkMoose that's correct. I just copypastad his code and patched it.

Comment: @cdkMoose it appears he has since edited his original post to remove the redundant if-else. I'll leave it in my answer as a form of eternal documentation. ;P

Comment: I see that Kevin edited the code in the posting after your answer.  If you are going to post a code solution though, it should still be one that works :)  The code in your answer will still throw an NRE.

Comment: @cdkMoose, actually he did. If you check the edit for his post, you will see that I really copypastad his original code.

Comment: Actually, if you check my code again, you'll see that it doesn't throw any exceptions because it IS being initialized at the beginning of the method.